# Writing C++ code for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to port an existing application from iOS to Android, 
The Application have core component implemented in C++

UI is specific to iOS implemented in Cocoa Framework,

I am good in C++ , objective C , average in Java

I wanted to know, the feasibility of developing android application, which has UI Part written in Java(UI) and Core Protocol implemented in C++, through googling, it seems Android NDK will come into Picture, but wanted to know, how complex to have such kind of Architecture,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible with NDK, but you will need to make several JNI calls, and it gets messy sometimes, especially when you are new to Android.

The alternative method is to create all UI in C/C++ itself, with your own UI library. 
This method is painful but it reap rewards in the long run if you are making a lot of apps which can cross port to ios/android, cutting down on UI rewrite costs.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to have C++ modules as a static library and link to it, with the UI ? , let it have too many Several JNI Call, but does it impact any performance? , i have worked on Core Part of Android OS like WebKit, There Whole Webkit written in C++ and perhaps UI is made up using Core Java, the same thing, won't goes here.....